# Rails 3.2: How do I access the current model instance inside of a helper module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, helper

In my rails model `Post.rb` I have the following methods setup:

```
  def category_names(seperator = ", ")
    categories.map(&:name).flatten.join(seperator).titleize
  end

  def publish_date
    read_attribute(:publish_date).strftime('%A, %b %d')
  end
```

I would like to move these into `PostsHelper` module under helpers. But get a no-method error when I do so because I guess the reference to `self` is lost.

So how can I fix this? Is a helper module the wrong place for these methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helper methods are designed mainly to be used in views, if I'm not mistaking.

What I'm sure about is your helper methods are outside of the scope of your model, meaning you need to pass to them the attribute to work with. Example:

```
  def category_names(categories, seperator = ", ")
    categories.map(&:name).flatten.join(seperator).titleize
  end
```

And call in your view:

```
category_names @post.categories
```

If you find your self writing "helper" method that are not exclusively used in your view, you could create a service object and include them in your model.

**Edit: Service object**

You can create a "services" directory under "app" directory and create your classes there.

Let me give you an example. I got a User model class, and I want to group all password related methods in a UserPassword service object.

User class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ::UserPassword
  ...
end
```

UserPassword service object:

```
require 'bcrypt'

module UserPassword
  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def authenticate(email, password)
      user = find_by_email email
      if user and user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
        user
      end
    end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
end
```

So my User *instanced object* (i.e `u = User.first`) can call `u.encrypt_password`, and my User *class* can call `User.authenticate`.

There is maybe other way, but I find it flexible and easy to write and maintain :)

Comment: What kind of directory would I place the service object under and what should I call it?

Comment: Edited my answer to add example of service object

Comment: Cool - this is the kind of answer I was hoping for

Comment: Sure - Check also AnkitG answer bellow about Concerns. Rails offer multiple ways to do what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Helpers are always intended to help views,  But if you want your Models to be clean and keep the unrelated methods as separate try using concerns in Rails 3. Concerns directory will be present by default in Rails 4.

There is a nice blogpost by DHH for same.

http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3372-put-chubby-models-on-a-diet-with-concerns